# How to write type definition with tokio_serde::SymmetricallyFramed::new()?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio, cbor

I am rying to serialize cbor using serde_tokio.
I can make a simple program work, but I need to actually store the tokio_serde::SymmetricallyFramed::new() in a structure to use it more than once.
(It consumes the socket, which is cool).

I can't seem to write a type that will store the value.

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_serde::formats::*;
use tokio_util::codec::{FramedWrite, LengthDelimitedCodec};

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    // Bind a server socket
    let socket = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:17653").await.unwrap();

    // Delimit frames using a length header
    let length_delimited = FramedWrite::new(socket, LengthDelimitedCodec::new());

    // Serialize frames with JSON
    let mut serialized = tokio_serde::SymmetricallyFramed::new(length_delimited, SymmetricalCbor::default());

    // Send the value
    serialized
        .send(vec![1i32,2,3])
        .await
        .unwrap()
}
```

produces the right output.  (Adopted from the json example in tokio-serde crate, here: https://github.com/carllerche/tokio-serde/blob/master/examples/client.rs

I want to put "serialized" into a structure (and hide how it is created in a fn), but I can't seem to write the right type.

```
use futures::prelude::*;
use serde_cbor;
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_serde::formats::*;
use tokio_util::codec::{FramedWrite, LengthDelimitedCodec};

type CborWriter = tokio_serde::Framed<tokio_util::codec::FramedWrite<tokio::net::TcpStream, tokio_util::codec::LengthDelimitedCodec>, serde_cbor::Value, serde_cbor::Value, tokio_serde::formats::Cbor<serde_cbor::Value, serde_cbor::Value>>;

// something like this has been suggested, but so far no luck.
// fn setup_writer(socket: tokio::net::TcpStream) -> impl Sink<??>+Debug {

fn setup_writer(socket: tokio::net::TcpStream) -> CborWriter {
    // Delimit frames using a length header
    let length_delimited = FramedWrite::new(socket, LengthDelimitedCodec::new());

    // Serialize frames with CBOR
    let serialized = tokio_serde::SymmetricallyFramed::new(length_delimited, SymmetricalCbor::default());

    return serialized;
}

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    // Bind a server socket
    let socket = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:17653").await.unwrap();

    // Serialize frames with CBOR
    let mut serialized = setup_writer(socket);

    // Send the value
    serialized
        .send(serde_cbor::Value::Array(vec![serde_cbor::Value::Integer(1i128),
                                            serde_cbor::Value::Integer(2i128),
                                            serde_cbor::Value::Integer(3i128)]))
        .await
        .unwrap()
}
```

But, I don't want to put cbor::Value in. I should just be able to put the Serializable objects in.  So I am obviously going in the wrong direction here.  The JSON example in the tokio-serde crate is happy to put in/out serde_json::Value, but I should have to do that, I think.

A suggestion on Discord was made to change the first example as:

```
    let mut serialized: () = tokio_serde::SymmetricallyFramed::new(length_delimited, SymmetricalCbor::default());
```

and let the compiler tell me what the type is:

```
   = note: expected unit type `()`
                 found struct `tokio_serde::Framed<tokio_util::codec::FramedWrite<tokio::net::TcpStream, tokio_util::codec::LengthDelimitedCodec>, _, _, tokio_serde::formats::Cbor<_, _>>`
```

Well, I can't put _ into the type alias, or write it directly.
I think it should say something like "impl Serialize", but that's not yet a thing.
Obviously, the compiler gets the first example right, so there must be something that will go in there... but what?